# Convert 2d char array to 1d string array

Tags: java, java-8

How to do this using stream?

For Ex:

```
char ch[0][]={'a','b','c'};
     ch[1][]={'d','e','f'};
     ch[2][]={'g','h','i'};
```

to:

```
String s[]={"abc","def","ghi"};
```

Comment: Did you try anything already? Show your attempt here.

Comment: @melwil not really because he is asking to do it with the Stream Api!

Comment: I concede the questions are to different to be duplicates. Carry on :-)

Comment: How is this question "too broad"?  It seems pretty straightforward to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use also the `Stream.of()` option rather than `Arrays.stream`.

```
char[][] ch = new char[3][];
ch[0] = new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c'};
ch[1] = new char[]{'d', 'e', 'f'};
ch[2] = new char[]{'g', 'h', 'i'};

String[] s = Stream.of(ch)
       .map(String::new)
       .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Or if you want to convert it to a `List<String>` :

```
List<String> list = Stream.of(ch)
        .map(String::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you all. I did try and search online but didn't figure it out.

Comment: @Quan When mine or Daniel Taubs' answer helped you: You might want to mark it as correct so others can see that you problem is fixed.

Answer (score 6):

The code explains itself. But please try *trying* next time.

```
char[][] ch = new char[3][];
ch[0] = new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c'};
ch[1] = new char[]{'d', 'e', 'f'};
ch[2] = new char[]{'g', 'h', 'i'};

String[] arr = Arrays.stream(ch)
        .map(String::new)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Was just about to post this exact solution!